# Why irreductible representation of $S_n$ are realisable over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm currently studying the article : "a New approach of representations of Sn" by Vershik et Okounkov" https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503040 . And I'am stuck in a key theorem.
I would like to show that every irreductible representation of $S_n$ are realisable over the field $\mathbb{Q}$. In order to do that, they chek the action of Coxeter generators and they verify that it defines a representation of $S_n$.
I realy don't understand the point of doing that and the link with the realisation of the representations over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: That's a 31 page paper. Where exactly is what you are looking at? In general, we know how many irreducible representations of $S_n$ there are, so if we can construct that many over $\mathbb{Q}$ then we are done. (Alternatively, one can use Artin's induction theorem to show that the number of irreducible reps of any finite group $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to the number of classes of cyclic subgroups of $G$. Since this is equal to the number of classes of elements for $S_n$, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a splitting field for $S_n$.)

Comment: My question is about the proposition 6.1 page 23. In this proposition, they write how the generators of coxeter act on a certain base but the matrix they found is not even in $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ so it's confusing..

Comment: Why is the matrix not in $\mathbb{Q}$? (6.3) and (6.4) look rational to me.